Is it safe teo pass high order function to view model from compsable for view model driven navigation?
I am having hard time to decide which way to use for view model driven navigation.
In my opinion, first way more easier but is it safe?
Second way may cause unwanted recompositions.
First way: Passing delegate to view model and invoking delegate after an API call.
@Composable
fun DummyScreen(
   viewModel = hiltViewModel()
   navController = rememberNavController()
) {
   LaunchEffect(Unit) { 
       viewModel.loadDataAndUpdateUiState()
   }

   val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
   when(uiState) {
      is UiState.Success -> { 
         viewModel.requestAPIandNavigate(
            id = ....
            onNavigate = { navController.navigateTo(destination) // <- is it safe to pass delegate?
         )
      }
    ....
}

Second way: Declaring a shared flow and emitting a value to trigger a block in composable to navigate
@Composable
fun DummyScreen(
   viewModel = hiltViewModel()
   navController = rememberNavController()
) {
   LaunchEffect(Unit) { 
       viewModel.loadDataAndUpdateUiState()
   }

   val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
   when(uiState) {
      is UiState.Success -> { 
         viewModel.requestAPIandNavigate(
            id = ....
         )
      }
   }

   val navigationDirection = viewModel.navigationDirection.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
   if (navigationDirection != null) {
      navController.navigateToDestinion(navigationDirection)
   }
   ....
}

